# PayPal Sandbox - Service Temporarily Unavailable

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm using **PayPal Express Checkout for Digital Goods**. I've tested it in **PayPal Sandbox** and it used to work fine.

Now, When i click in **Pay With PayPal button**. It gives me **503 error** and tell me this

"**Service Temporarily Unavailable.** The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later."

Is it true that PayPal system have a maintenance? Because, I've tested for two days and the result is still the same. I've check in PayPal notify website, but it doesn't give any information about Sandbox maintenance.

Does anyone here also have the same issue with me?

Thank you

Comment: There hasn't been any extended downtime for Digital Goods. What URL are you redirecting to? Does the account you're using have Digital Goods enabled on it?

Comment: I've found the problem. When i open developer.paypal.com and login using my paypal account. Then i open my website, and start a payment using PayPal Sandbox. It will show me 503 error above. To fix this, i need to re-open my browser, then i don't open developer.paypal.com earlier and don't login, and start a payment. It works fine.

Comment: To do SetExpressCheckout i redirect to `https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp`and to display PayPal Payment Form, i'm using javascript in `https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/dg.js`

Comment: I'm still getting 503 when I trying to sign up to Sandbox

Comment: even am also facing the same problem, any help would be appreciated